# Trace of a matrix equation

Tags: derivatives, matrix-equations, trace

If I have a matrix equation like

$$e = \operatorname{sign}(Bx - Cd) : (Bx - Cd)$$

were $B$ and $C$ are matrix and $x$ and $d$ are vectores, and I need to find the gradient of e in sense of x, $\nabla e$. How can I take this derivative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $M=(Bx-Cd)$ 

then the function, differential, and gradient are (respectively)
$$\eqalign{
 e &= {\rm sign}(M):M \cr
de &= {\rm sign}(M):dM = {\rm sign}(M):B\,dx = B^T{\rm sign}(M):dx \cr
\nabla e = \frac{\partial e}{\partial x} &= B^T{\rm sign}(M) \cr\cr
}$$
The gradient is undefined wherever a component of $M$ is equal to zero.